# global javascript variable becomes undefined inside part of object constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to refactor some code, and I am having an issue where a global variable is defined properly in one part of an object constructor function but is undefined in another part of the same function.

I defined some global variables as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var imgWidth;
  var imgHeight;
```

Then I wrote an object constructor function. The ultimate goal is to create an object for an image that has within it: the actual image object, the width (defined as the actual image width / 2), the height (defined as the actual image height / 2), x position (manually specified), and y position (manually specified).

```
function Character(name, x, y){
    //define the image object within the Character
    this.imageObject = new Image();
    //using base-64 encoded data in place of an image url, just for the demo
    this.imageObject.src = name+'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAW0lEQVR42mL8//8/AzpgZGTcC6KBcs5wMRwK/0MVMsLEmLAoEmXAApiwiKUhaRJCltgLsQVsWwIQ/wTx0fBeRigD7B6Y24i1mj4Kn4KI7Uie2Y7FI8+B2AMgwABjRynfWgpcxQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

    console.log(this.imageObject);
    console.log(this.imageObject.src);

    //set natural width and natural height once the image is loaded
    if (this.imageObject.addEventListener){
        this.imageObject.addEventListener('load', function(){
            console.log('this.naturalWidth for '+this.src+' = '+this.naturalWidth);
            window.imgWidth = this.naturalWidth/2;
            window.imgHeight = this.naturalHeight/2;
            console.log('imgWidth inside imageObject event listener for '+this.src+' = '+window.imgWidth);
        });
    } else if (this.imageObject.attachEvent){
        this.imageObject.attachEvent('onload', function(){
            console.log('this.naturalWidth for '+this.src+' = '+this.naturalWidth);
            window.imgWidth = this.naturalWidth/2;
            window.imgHeight = this.naturalHeight/2;
            console.log('imgWidth inside imageObject event listener for '+this.src+' = '+window.imgWidth);
        });
    }
    //set natural width and natural height to object
    this['w'] = this['w0'] = window.imgWidth;
    this['h'] = this['h0'] = window.imgHeight;

    //set initial x and y position
    this['x'] = x;
    this['y'] = y;

    console.log('imgWidth inside character constructor = '+window.imgWidth);

}
```

I call the function like so, immediately inside document ready:

```
var sun0 = new Character('data:text/javascript;base64,', 1, 0);
```

When inspecting the console in Chrome, the console.log lines output as follows:

```
console.log(this.imageObject); //the image object as expected
console.log(this.imageObject.src); //the image url as expected
console.log('this.naturalWidth for '+this.src+' = '+this.naturalWidth); //10 as expected
console.log('imgWidth inside imageObject event listener for '+this.src+' = '+window.imgWidth); //5 as expected
console.log('imgWidth inside character constructor = '+window.imgWidth); //undefined
```

Why is window.imgWidth undefined here? Is there a better way to create this object so that it has a property of w, which is 1/2 of the image's natural width?

[JS Fiddle - open the console to see the messages](https://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/2p5xaaaa/embedded/result/)

Comment: when you are storing the width and height, the image has not loaded yet... Asynchronous process, hence why you have load events...

Comment: you can't define globals using `var ` in a function. move the declaration outside of the ready() or use `window.imgWidth=x` to create a global from within a function.

Comment: Is your code all executing inside `$(document).ready(function(){/* in here */})`?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ ...` creates it's own scope, so declaring variables inside that function does not make those variables globals.

Comment: @PHPglue yes, it is all executing inside `$(document).ready(function(){`. I see from the other comments that actually creates its own scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it becomes 'undefined' is because you set the imgWidth variable from within an event handler function which only executes at some point in the future. Event handler functions happen asynchronously - that is, at some point in the future whilst program execution continues on the code after the event handler declaration.

When then event handler function is declared, the code will continue to run and execute these lines BEFORE the onload event handler gets called:

```
//set natural width and natural height to object
this['w'] = this['w0'] = window.imgWidth;
this['h'] = this['h0'] = window.imgHeight;

//set initial x and y position
this['x'] = x;
this['y'] = y;
```

At this point, the onload event handler hasnt been called (fired), so the runtime environment will correctly complain that window.imgWidth is undefined.

If you wanted this code to run, the simplest way would be to add the above to the event handler routines like this:

```
this.imageObject.attachEvent('onload', function(){
    console.log('this.naturalWidth for '+this.src+' = '+this.naturalWidth);
    window.imgWidth = this.naturalWidth/2;
    window.imgHeight = this.naturalHeight/2;
    console.log('imgWidth inside imageObject event listener for '+this.src+' = '+window.imgWidth);

    //set natural width and natural height to object
    this['w'] = this['w0'] = window.imgWidth;
    this['h'] = this['h0'] = window.imgHeight;

    //set initial x and y position
    this['x'] = x;
    this['y'] = y;
    console.log('imgWidth inside character constructor = '+window.imgWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare and use a global scope variable, I think one of the best ways is to be super clear about it:

window.someGlobalVariable = 4;

The problem you appear to be having, is that you're not actually in the global scope but in a function scope. to be precise: in the callback on DOM-ready.

Answer (score 0):

This should demonstrate the issue with local and global scope variables:

```
// imgWidth hasn't been defined yet
console.log('before ready statement: ' + typeof imgWidth);

$(window).ready(function() {
  // here we are defining a local variable named imgWidth 
  var imgWidth = 100;

});

console.log('after ready statement: ' + typeof imgWidth);


// imgWidth hasn't been defined yet
console.log('before ready statement: ' + typeof imgHeight);

$(window).ready(function() {
  // here we are defining a a global variable named imgHeight 
  window.imgHeight = 200;

});

console.log('after ready statement: ' + typeof imgHeight);
console.log('imgHeight is ' + imgHeight);
```

Output:

```
before ready statement: undefined
after ready statement: undefined
before ready statement: number
after ready statement: number
imgHeight is 200
```